# How to authenticate a web service hit from a non liferay app

Tags: web-services, session, authentication, liferay, portlet

I have made a **remote json web service** in liferay in 'ServiceImpl' & its occurring in list of web services on page **http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws** & also working fine. But it works only when I am logged in the application on browser.
What I am not getting is that, how would I **authenticate** the hit if some other **non liferay application** would use it, where there will be **no session** of my application, means from where we will get that **p_auth** token. Means do I need a session of user on my application?
Thanks.

Comment: how can i **authenticate** the **web services** using **OAuth**,means how to implement it. I want to hit web services from **Postman** using **OAuth** then it should return data. I want the **token** based authentication, how is it possible in **liferay**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to authenticate from the client you are calling for example using java can use an Apache Http client with a preemtive basic authentication 
[ClientPreemptiveBasicAuthentication](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientPreemptiveBasicAuthentication.java)

or using curl for example this way

```
curl http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/user/get-user-by-email-address \
  -u test@liferay.com:test \
  -d companyId=20154 \
  -d emailAddress='test@liferay.com'
```

for more info see

[JSON WS Security](https://web.liferay.com/it/web/tomas.polesovsky/blog/-/blogs/json-ws-security)

[Liferay docs](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/json-web-services-invocation-examples)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Sheshi, what I have tried is from a normal **java project** in **main method** hit that **remote service**,it is working, i want to know is it the correct way?

Comment: URL url = new URL("http: //localhost:8080/api/jsonws/survey-portlet.survey/hello-world/world-name/test");  
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");  
     String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(new String("test@liferay.com:test").getBytes());  
  
     conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+ encoding);